# How to maintain video cover entire div

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-video

I used coverr background video for my site but when I resize it mobile then to desktop view again, video have extra spaces. I think this is happening also in Coverr.co website. Not sure if they have support.

How can I maintain the video covered the entire div? Is this can be fixed through css media query or need to modify the javascript code of coverr?

I tried object-fit cover but I think there's no work around for IE Edge.

Thanks!
[image]

Here's the jquery code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  scaleVideoContainer();

  initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
  initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
  initBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    scaleVideoContainer();
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
  });
});

function scaleVideoContainer() {

  var height = $(window).height() + 5;
  var unitHeight = parseInt(height) + 'px';
  $('.homepage-hero-module').css('height',unitHeight);

}

function initBannerVideoSize(element){

  $(element).each(function(){
    $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
    $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
  });

  scaleBannerVideoSize(element);

}

function scaleBannerVideoSize(element){

  var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
  windowHeight = $(window).height() + 5,
  videoWidth,
  videoHeight;

  // console.log(windowHeight);

  $(element).each(function(){
    var videoAspectRatio = 
    $(this).data('height')/$(this).data('width');

    $(this).width(windowWidth);

    if(windowWidth < 1000){
        videoHeight = windowHeight;
        videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
        $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'});

        $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight);
    }

    $('.homepage-hero-module .video-container video').addClass('fadeIn animated');

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; ">

    <video width="100% " controls>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4 " type="video/mp4 ">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg " type="video/ogg "> Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem is with this block of code:

```
if(windowWidth < 1000){
    videoHeight = windowHeight;
    videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
    $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'});
    $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight);
}
```

So, when you resize it to mobile, and then back, it still has the above CSS. What I did to fix it, was to include an 'else', for when you resize it back:

```
if(windowWidth < 1000){
    videoHeight = windowHeight;
    videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
    $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'}                
    $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight)
}
else{
    // this resets the CSS applied above
    $(this).css({'margin-top' : '', 'margin-left' : ''});
    $(this).width(windowWidth).height("");
}
```

Hope this helps!